# WAMP: Listen for file change notifications in directory (recursive)

Tags: php, notifications, wamp, windows-8.1, file-management

The closest answer to this question I have found is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9628074/listening-folders-and-files-changes).

I want to implement a file mirroring application, written in PHP/MySQL, running on WAMP. My problem is **how to monitor if files are changed, added or deleted** from a file system directory, triggering a PHP script when such an event occurs (and passing details of changes)

I only need it to work on windows (8.1). It will be a large number of files, so would most likely be impractical to periodically scan all files for modification/size changes (Although I will do this as a last resort). At a later date, I may want to use hashes for comparing files which would certainly be impractical if all files had to be hashed in each scan to detect changes.

Microsoft gives some details on how to implement a listener [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365261%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), written in C if I'm correct. I don't know how easy this would be for someone with little or no experience in C windows programming though - especially if I want it to interact with PHP.

Are there any 3rd party libraries or implementations etc which could be integrated with PHP? Or any other methods?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to get details of file changes are made too?

Comment: I may decide to, but I will use subversion for that, in a separate workflow. I considered using subversion for all the files but it would in my opinion overcomplicate the situation as I will only need details of changes for at most 0.1% of the files - most of the files will be fairly large binaries.

Comment: Then why don't use hashes. I am sure they are practical. If you can explain how hashes are not helpful for you, I can suggest other alternates.

Comment: Using Windows API with PHP is not a good idea and will definitely make it very complicated. If you use a listener using Windows API, it will also have to run 24*7 to constantly monitoring every changes. So, you may also have to create a CLI PHP script.